# Mac OS external monitor cannot play streaming video in Safari

Tags: macos, safari

I have a brand new MBP, I have tried everything that I can think of and googling and apple support is no help.

In safari 15.1 , a clean install of it, I cannot play streaming video on external monitor through thunderbolt.

If I have the MBP unplugged, it plays the video in safari no problem. However the moment that I hook up an external display, the video play back in safari does not work.

Edge, Chrome, Firefox, DuckDuck Go, and Opera all work fine. this is 100% a browser issue with Safari and Only while hooked up to an external monitor.

Any idea?

Comment: You may get better answers on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (Apple hardware/software) Stack Exchange.

Comment: You may also want to try multiple websites/videos/external monitors to be sure it's not a codec issue.

Comment: Ya its not on YouTube, but Hulu, Netflix, Peacock, Amazon Prime don't work.